# C# Winforms: How to send dataset changes from UI layer to Data layer (dataGridView)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a problem when I try to send changes from the UI layer (DataGridView) to the data layer. When I do the queries and connection directly in the form class everything works fantastic. When I separate the data layer and the UI, a problem occurs.

The program successfully loads the data into the dataGridView, only when I make changes to the column and press enter I get the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

I know what is this error and i try to debug and aslo try to see whay is that object is not initialized!

Here is my code!

**Data layer**

```
namespace App.Data
{
    public class PartnerRepository
    {
        public MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
        public DataTable dt;
        public DataSet ds ;
        public MySqlConnection conn;
        public MySqlCommand cmd;
        public MySqlCommandBuilder builder;
   }

   public DataSet AddressListDataSet(int id)
   {
            using (conn = new MySqlConnection(DB.connString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("...query...", conn);
                this.ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }

            return ds;
    }

  public void SaveAddressChangesData()
  {
            try
            {
                DataSet changes = this.ds.GetChanges();
                if (changes != null)
                {
                    builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

                    int updatedRows = this.adapter.Update(changes);
                   
                   this.ds.AcceptChanges();

                }
                else
                {
                    //...
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.ds.RejectChanges();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Form**

```
namespace App.UI
{
    public partial class PartnerForm : Form
    {
        public App.Data.PartnerRepository PartnerRepository
        {
            get { return new App.Data.PartnerRepository(); }
        }

        private DataSet AddressDataSet;

        public PartnerForm ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.AddressDataSet = PartnerRepository.AddressListDataSet();
            this.addressDataGridView.DataSource = this.AddressDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }

        // Save changes to db
        private void addressDataGridView_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {

                if (this.AddressDataSet.GetChanges() != null)
                {
                    this.PartnerRepository.SaveAddressChangesData();  // ERROR
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I realy dont want to put data layer in UI i need to separate it. I also try to pass modified dataset to data layer and merge with existing. The error is some!

Can someone see code and tell me where i make mistake.

Comment: [Work with datasets in n-tier applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/work-with-datasets-in-n-tier-applications?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/3110834)

Comment: Hint: `ds` is `null` when you call `this.PartnerRepository.SaveAddressChangesData();` because `this.PartnerRepository` property returns a **new** instance of the data class. The `ds` is being created in the `AddressListDataSet` method not on creating a new object. So, the very first line `DataSet changes = this.ds.GetChanges();` is accessing a method of a `null` object thus the exception. You should read the `catch (Exception ex)` msg.

Comment: I debug it and pass ds like argument. But problem is how to pass adapter to data layer

Comment: You should not have any data access objects (MySqlDataAdapter, MySqlConnection,, MySql...etc) in the UI layer, otherwise, you're not separating the layers. Pass business objects/data containers (like DataTable) between the two layers. Or add a business logic layer (BLL) that manages the communications between the UI and DAL layers. The link in the first comment is a good start.

Comment: For your code as is, try something. Make the `SaveAddressChangesData` a static method that returns a `DataTable/Set` (If you have just one table then no need to use a DataSet). Do the same for the `SaveAddressChangesData` method and add to it a parameter of type `DataTable/Set`. In your implementation, keep the instance in a class field (or cast it from the grid's DataSource property). In other words, get from and pass to `PartnerRepository` class data containers/business objects through static methods where you read from and write to the database.

Comment: I slove it using Singleton instance.